# connect to server and execute multiple commands

Tags: mysql, c, ssh, pipe

This was my previous question:

> Can someone give me simple example in C, of using `pipe()` system call to and use ssh to connect to a remote server and execute a simple `ls` command and parse the reply.  Thanks in advance, [...]

I got an answer for that, but I need something more.

I would like to ask how to use a pipe and connect to a remote server using ssh, then open mysql and execute a simple query like `SELECT * FROM tables;`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already know how to run ls, what's the problem? Just change `ls` to `mysql -B -e 'select * from tables'`. Oh, and why are you doing this instead of using the MySQL C interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this for a challenge?, if yes that's cool because you are doing a hard thing to the end, if not **derobert** suggestion is the best solution in case you want to communicate with the MySQL server.

Comment: @Prasanth Madhavan: I think you've misunderstood what the 'mysql' command line program does. Opening it with a pipe is *less* direct because the MySQL command line program... uses the C API. Using the C API is *more* direct.